# Start a service when app is terminated via push notification

Tags: android, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to implement a background location tracking via a sticky notification, i can easily start the service with the notification if the app is in the foreground or open in the task manager of the phone, however i want to trigger the service start via a push notification for example, whenever i do so, i can't seem to start the service at all and the `onMessageReceived` only triggers the `super.onMessageReceived`, is there a work around for this?

here's the code i have in the method

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) startForegroundService(intent) else startService(intent)
    }
}
```

by triggering the super i mean that it only displays the default notification with the title/description i wrote on the firebase cloud messaging tab

Answer (score 0):

You need to write sending FCM notification api in which you will be require 'data' key instead of 'notification'.

```
{
"data": {"description": "TEST", 
"jobCode": "TEST", 
"notification_id": "2",
"body": {"id":"25719","title":"Tele Consulant ","description":"Appointment","text":"Appointment","is_read":0,"opponentsID":"22297","contactIdentifier":"Test Doctor","roomName":"1","eventName":"accept"},
"type": "3",
"Image" : "", 
"title" :" Tele Consulant "},
"to":"c5fHUz8iRh63gXxAR9NYXG:APA91bE78n7Nc4sNxgeETiYo5XYsw0Trhqj1V_vZEaQsoCZg-0n-IhEJ2tJTPAlv0R2Xka3HEwdOw6_kSNqCUHBZmhluDNsAtM8u_GHFjMoaucuCGtjSURq2GIfP5Kgv03j7lCdN8ZjK"
}
```

**Types of messages:**

> Notification Messages and Data Messages.
>
> Notification messages contain a predefined set of user-visible keys.
> Notification messages have an optional notification payload and will
> be delivered to the users system tray.
>
> If the app is in foreground, they will call onMessageReceived, if the
> notification has data payload.
>
> If the application is background, the notification will be displayed
> and the data payload is given through the intent of the launching
> activity.
>
> If the notification has no optional data payload, the notification
> will be displayed and the application is opened when clicked.
>
> Data Messages contain only your user-defined custom key-value pairs.
> (explained below). And if you want that the message consistently call
> the onMessageReceived, they should not contain a notification payload,
> but a data payload.

Comment: i did try sending a notification with "data" but it still won't start the service if the app is completely terminated, it must be in the background at the very least

Comment: basically what happens in the case that the app is terminated, it ignores the code written in onMessageReceived, and defaults to the super.onMessageReceived which displays the normal title/description from firebase